# how to change the secs to the ISO time format?

Tags: python

How to change the secs to the ISO time format:

for example:

28800 sec is the offset from the midnight? if successfully converted, the output should be 08:00:00 not 8:00:00.

How could I do it in python? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using timedelta to 'do the math'

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Can easily get the values for today programmatically
# but ommitted here for brevity
midnight = datetime(2013, 10, 18)
delta = timedelta(seconds=28800)

offset_time = midnight + delta
print offset_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

>>> 08:00:00
```